# R step by step processioning time

Tags: r, debugging, profiling

in my long R script I want to find out how much processioning time take by each line. To do this I am using

```
foo1 = sys.time()
foo <- function(x){
   t1 = sys.time()
   y=x*x
   t2 = sys.time(); t2-t1
   for (i in 1:10)
       {z=y*y}
   sys.time()-t2
   # and so on
}
Sys.time()-foo1
```

This is very cumbersome approach and not suitable for large codes. How can I get the time take by each step/line of a function with line number?

Comment: why is it voted as close?

Comment: I think you can simply return diff in Sys.time() ( but its bad idea) foo <- function(x){ b=numeric() a=Sys.time() y=xx b[1]=Sys.time()-a a=Sys.time() for (i in 1:10000) {z=yy} b[2]=Sys.time()-a return(b) # and so on } i=foo(13)

Comment: The problem with  Sys.time() approach is that if you have 100s of lines of code it is very difficult to do so.

Comment: Yes) I told its bad idea)